# how to call web service in java using post method

Tags: java, web-services

```
public static String[] Webcall(String emailID) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(AppConfig.URL + emailID);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("userEmailId", emailID);
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            org.json.JSONObject _jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(output);
            org.json.JSONArray _jArray = _jsonObject.getJSONArray("manager");
            String[] str = new String[_jArray.length()];

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;

    }
```

This is my code I am trying to call web service and get data.

But when I hit web service then I am getting below exception

> Failed : HTTP error code : 404

Please suggest me where am doing wrong try to give solution for this .

Comment: Sorry, you don't know what 404 means?

Comment: why this error is coming can u please tell

Comment: google 404 http

Comment: 404 means that the url is not correct.  The resource is not found

Comment: 404 means the web url you are calling does not exist.

Comment: while i am hitting in post man i am getting response

Comment: my suggest is use **Retrofit**

Comment: Here is Retrofit : http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: And you can see this for easier implementaion :) : http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: Use Volley Library

Comment: I am not using android i am using java  in jsp

Comment: Why is `android` tag added ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is check url is it working on computer using postman or restclient and if it is working fine then tried to post using below code, this code is for posting data in json format using **HttpPost** you can use retrofit lib as Milad suggested.

```
public static String POST(String url, String email)
{
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            String json = "";
            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("email", email);
            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }



private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u should try to re-check URL that you send request to.
follow the output error, code 404 that mean the URL is broken or dead link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same by using jersy-client and jersy core.Here is the code snippet

```
    private static void generateXML(String xmlName, String requestXML, String url)
  {
    try
    {
      Client client = Client.create();
      WebResource webResource = client
        .resource(url);
      ClientResponse response = (ClientResponse)webResource.accept(new String[] { "application/xml" }).post(ClientResponse.class, requestXML);
      if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
      }
      String output = (String)response.getEntity(String.class);
      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(xmlName, "UTF-8");
      writer.println(output);
      writer.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      try {
        throw new CustomException("Rest-Client May Be Not Working From Your System");
      } catch (CustomException e1) {
        System.exit(1);
      }
    }
  }
```

Call this method from your code with varibales.